# Projecting a texture from plane to object with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapping, textures, texture-mapping, texturing

I'm trying to project a texture from a plane to a wall using raycasts. This should happen in realtime. Since the plane is larger than the wall, only part of the texture is supposed to appear on the front side of the wall. So moving the plane will also change the part of the texture on the wall. The wall can have windows etc so it's not just a simple cube. I already managed to get the texturecoordinates using raycasts, but I haven't yet managed to correctly put the texture on the wall. Any ideas how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need a [projector](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html), this enables you to project an image on any model. It's mostly used for shadows but anything can be projected anywhere!